# Insert results from SQL query into php array

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

I trying to insert SQL query results to PHP array:

```
$sql= $conn -> prepare("SELECT top(10) code, name, SUM(minutes)as total  FROM db_name group by code, name ORDER BY total desc");
$sql -> execute();

$combinedResults = array();
while ($row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $combinedResults[$row['code']][] = array( 
    'Name' => $row['name'],
    'Total' => $row['total']    );
};
echo($combinedResults['code'][0]['Total']);
?>
```

and script return `Undefined index: code` in echo row

Comment: result of print_r($combinedResults) and $row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

Change

```
$combinedResults[$row['code']][] = array(
```

to

```
$combinedResults['code'][$row['code']] = array(
```

Comment: I don't think its a typo.

Comment: Working now but return only one column name: print_r($combinedResults['code'][0]'Total']); return 135 but print_r($combinedResults['code'][0]['Name']['Total']); return only one letter of record

Comment: @Klapsius When you are developing, please set `display_errors` to `on` and `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` (or -1).  You will have noticed that the index does not exist.  PHP will issue warnings and notices.  It will also treat `['Total`]` as `[0]` and only display the first character of `$combinedResults['code'][0]['Name']`.  You need to do: `print_r($combinedResults['code'][0]['Total']);` to see the `Total`

Answer (score 0):

Here your "code" index must be value from the database. That's why there is no such index in associative array. Or, if you need "code" index, you need to rewrite like this (if I've understood correctly):

```
while ($row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $combinedResults['code'][] = array( 
   'Name' => $row['name'],
   'Total' => $row['total']    );
};
```